# How to set background color of QComboBox button?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, qt5, qtstylesheets

Version/Environment:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Qt 5.11.0 MSVC2017 64 bit

I have a simple [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qcombobox.html) to enable/disable a feature:

```
QComboBox *onOffComboBox = new QComboBox();
onOffComboBox->insertItem(0, "Off");
onOffComboBox->insertItem(1, "On");
```

The combo box is added as a cell widget to a table:

```
this->ui->settingsTable->setCellWidget(rowNumber, 1, onOffComboBox);
```

[image]

Now i want to change the background color of the button but not the select items.

My first approach was simply to use `QWidget`'s [`setStyleSheet`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) function:

```
onOffComboBox->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");
```

But this suppresses the standard style:

[image]

I also used variations with specific [`QComboBox` styles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls) according to the documentation:

```
onOffComboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox::drop-down {background: red;}");
```

But this only colors the part with the arrow and suppresses it's style:

[image]

Using just `QComboBox {background: red;}` has the same result as with `background-color: red;` just the select items are not colored.

Just as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178521/5233188) answer another approach is to use `QPallete`:

```
QPalette pal = onOffComboBox->palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Base, QColor("red"));
onOffComboBox->setPalette(pal);
onOffComboBox->update(); // just in case this has any effect
```

This only colors the select items:

[image]

I also tried nearly all other `QPalette` [color roles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum):

- `QPalette::Window`, `QPalette::Foreground`, `QPalette::Button` - do nothing
- `QPalette::Base` - colors the select items (see pic)
- `QPalette::Text` - colors the text of the button and the select items

#### So, how can i change the color of the `QComboBox` drop-down button background WITHOUT overwritting or suppressing the standard style?

The styles of the pop-up items also shouldn't change.

Here is an image of what i want:

[image]

Comment: By "button", are you referring to the down-arrow?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS No, the whole rectangle to click on to select an item...

Comment: @goulashsoup Do you want to change the background color of the popup items ,? you also mention something of the selected item that I do not understand, please do not use the term button if what you indicated above is correct because it brings confusion

Comment: @eyllanesc I added an image which shows what the desired outcome is... Actually the official documentation also uses the word _button_: [_The drop-down button of a QComboBox._](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#drop-down-sub).

Comment: @goulashsoup okay, then you do not want to change the color of the popup items so my premise was wrong

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, the bg-color of the pop-up items should stay white, selected/hovered blue...

Comment: Here https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet/blob/master/qdarkstyle/style.qss style for all widgets. Just use what you need and edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QComboBox` is always tricky to customize because it is made of subwidgets (even conditional subwidgets).
I made tests and your simple stylesheet `QComboBox {background:red}` works almost fine for me on Linux, except that the box-border is also red in the dropdown. The behaviour seems to be different depending on the [GUI style](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#details).

From the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls) :

> Note: With complex widgets such as QComboBox and QScrollBar, if one
>   property or sub-control is customized, all the other properties or
>   sub-controls must be customized as well.

It looks like you have to customize everything if you want to customize the *button*... Then it would not be possible to change the colour without overwriting or suppressing the standard style.

You could style the whole drop-down to mimic the native look, but it's not nice to do and not robust (and not portable).

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: white;
  selection-background-color: blue;
}
QComboBox {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: You nailed it. I had hoped that i could access the native looks style somehow but this seems not possible.

Comment: Maybe there is a very tricky way to do so that I am missing, but according to the doc this is not possible straight-forward. I asked a related question to your problem, but I don't think it is possible either : https://stackoverflow.com/q/54403698/6165833