# How can I restore default system value of a QSS property?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

Qt QSS is propagated to children, if one parent set its stylesheet to `color: red`, all its children will apply this stylesheet. If you set explicitely `QLabel {color: red}`, then only QLabel children will be concerned.

It is possible to overwrite the stylesheet on children, if they set their own values `children->setStyleSheet("color: blue");` but I could not find a way to reset the property to the default value. The value set by the system or Qt, if we had not set this property in any parent's stylesheet.

How could I achieve something like `children->setStyleSheet("color: default");` ?

Comment: In my project, I hacked it by settings values with `args` for example `children->setStyleSheet(QString("color : %1).arg(oColorStr));`